# How to resize a three.js object in-place (i.e. keep at its position)

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a sphere of dots that I'd like to animate. Ideally, each dot would stay at the surface of the sphere as it resizes. My current approach is to scale the mesh/geometry of a particular point on the surface, but it seems like the dot disappears under the sphere.

```js
const dotGeometry = new three.CircleGeometry(2, 5)
const vector = new three.Vector3()
vector.setFromSphericalCoords(radius, point.phi, point.theta)

// Make it look at the target from the origin 
// to have the same slope at the surface of the sphere.
dotGeometry.lookAt(vector)

// Move the geometry to the desired point.
dotGeometry.translate(vector.x, vector.y, vector.z)

const dot = new three.Mesh(dotGeometry, dotMaterial)
scene.add(dot)

{
  // Animation in render function
  const fi = 3 * time * 0.001
  const r = Math.abs(Math.asin(Math.sin(fi)))
  dot.scale.set(r, r, r)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the original approach is that as you are scaling the "visible" part of the dot, you are scaling its whole geometry. Because of that, its position changes as you try to enlarge it.

The easiest way to achieve the desired effect is to split the dot into a container object and a dot geometry. This way, when you scale the dot, you'll be scaling it at (0,0,0) in container geometry and thus not moving it.

The container object is then moved to the desired destination, where you can scale the dot at the origin.

```js
const container = new three.Group()

const vector = new three.Vector3()
vector.setFromSphericalCoords(radius, point.phi, point.theta)

container.position.x = vector.x
container.position.y = vector.y
container.position.z = vector.z

const dotGeometry = new three.CircleGeometry(2, 5)

dotGeometry.lookAt(vector)
const dot = new three.Mesh(dotGeometry, dotMaterial)

container.add(dot)
scene.add(container)

//

{
  // Animation in render function
  const fi = 3 * time * 0.001
  const r = Math.abs(Math.asin(Math.sin(fi)))
  dot.scale.set(r, r, r)
}
```